# Need advice on an application hanging

Tags: multithreading, windbg, dispatcher

I need your advice because I am facing with a sneaky problem of thread interblocking.

My application is using WPF with Framework.NET 4.5. I use a lot of Dispatcher.Invoke() and I suspect one of my thread is blocking the others threads to run.

Using WinDbg, I made an extract of all threads in my .NET application but I cannot find the thread which is blocking the rest of my application.

My Windbg log is too big to show it here so I have uploaded it into pastebin: http://pastebin.ca/3057001

Comment: load the dmp in DebugDiag (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42933) Analyzer, select crash/hang analysis and let the tool check the dmp. Look if this helps you.

Comment: `Symbol search path is: *** Invalid ***`, `Symbols can not be loaded because symbol path is not initialized.`, `*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found`, `***    Your debugger is not using the correct symbols`

Comment: After you fixed the symbols, you can try SOSEX's `!dlk` command